# ngModel not showing data when using promises

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a form that uses ngModel to show data.  It works great if I just load the information synchronously however when I try to use asynchronous code code nothing ever shows up. I know the field names are correct since, as I said, it works with synchronous code. I am sure it is something stupid I missed but I cannot figure out what.
Here are some code snippits:

userinformation.service.ts

```
getuserinformation(): Promise<UserInformation> {
            return Promise.resolve(MOCKUSERINFORMATION[0]);
        }
```

userinformation.component.ts

```
getUserInformation(): void {
        this.userinformationservice.getuserinformation().then(userdata => this.userinfo = userdata);
    }
```

userinformation.component.html

```
<input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" name="FirstName" id="firstname" required="required" placeholder="First Name" class="required" ([ngModel])="userinfo.FirstName"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using the wrong type of C# MVC Controller.  I was using one based off of the "Controller" object which should be used for redirecting the user within the code (not needed since I am using Angular) when I should have been using the "ApiController" which returns an "IHttpActionResult" object which I can then translate using ".map(response => response.json())" correctly.

Answer (score 0):

At first `([...])` is invalid. It's named banana-in-a-box for a reason ;-)

Should be

```
[(ngModel)]="userinfo.FirstName"
```

In your case this will still cause an error because when `userinfo` is `null`, `userinfo.FirstName` is undefined.

This should work

```
[ngModel]="userinfo?.FirstName" (ngModelChange)="userinfo && userinfo.FirstName = $event"
```

or alternatively

```
*ngIf="userinfo" [(ngModel)]="userinfo.FirstName"
```

This way the `<input>` well not be shown while `userinfo` is not yet set.

Comment: I must be doing something else wrong since neither of those worked.  I do not get the information to ever show up.  It does show up if I put the single entry into a list and then use a *ngFor loop.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post the code that demonstrates what you tried. Hard to tell what you might have done wrong.

Comment: I was able to rewrite the code completely to get it to work.  Turns out I was using the wrong kind of C# MVC controller and once I used the correct one everything worked fine.